# Can't import poppler.h

Tags: c++, c, include, poppler

I have decided to write a pdf viewer as a hobby project. So I went through source codes of pdf viewers zathura and evince. They used the poppler library to work with pdfs.
For some reason I am not able to import the poppler.h header like they do in their code. I get the following error:

```
fatal error: poppler.h: No such file or directory
```

So the poppler.h file does exist on my machine but as poppler/glib/poppler.h
So when I try to do

```
#include<poppler/glib/poppler.h>
```

I get the error:

```
fatal error: glib-object.h: No such file or directory
```

If I am missing some very fundamental or obvious fact (which I probably am :( ) please point me to the correct resources.

Edit:
Compiling the code with `-I` flag in the following way worked for me:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags cairo poppler glib-2.0` temp.c `pkg-config --cflags cairo poppler glib-2.0`
```

Comment: You probably need to pass the `-I` option to your compiler when compiling code. You need to figure out what that option should be. In fact, if you were to go through and read poppler's documentation you will likely find that it explains how to properly configure your source in order to use this library.

Comment: Yes. This worked! Didn't find anything in poppler documentation. I used the following line to compile:
`gcc \`pkg-config --cflags cairo poppler glib-2.0\` temp.c \`pkg-config --cflags cairo poppler glib-2.0\``
This basically same as the `-I` option.
But I also had to manually include cairo and glib-2.0. Is there any way to make the compiler automatically detect the files to be included? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Free software packages typically include an autoconf script and an automake-generated makefile that do all this work, automatically.